# Kinetic.js removing an image from the layer and redrawing by adding new images

Tags: kineticjs

I have created a kinetic.js layer and added some images on it. 
Now i want to remove all the images and redraw the layer by adding some new images(like a second level images for a game).  I have tried using the layer.remove(image) function.

But after the redraw the old images are still shown whereas the new images are not added.

Could anyone help me to solve this issue..?

Comment: Please add the work you have done so far. This would increase the possibility of getting good answers fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use

```
layer.removeChildren();
layer.draw();
layer.add(newRectWhatever);
```

and that works for me.